# How can I send message or do something in a specific discord server using discord.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js, bots

**How can I send a message or assign a role on a specific discord server from the discord server's Id?**

(My goal is to make a discord bot and when someone does something in my website, it will give a api call to my discord.js and it will give a role in the specific discord server he/she selected.)

I just wanted to do
https://discord.com/developers/docs/resources/guild#add-guild-member-role
this in discord.js. But it seems like discord.js adds role to the server where an event ran.

Comment: You should probably have a look at the discord.js API first, this seems like a request for an entire feature implementation rather than just a question.

Comment: @GauravPunjabi I just wanted to do https://discord.com/developers/docs/resources/guild#add-guild-member-role this from discord.js. But couldn't find where to specify the guild ID in discord.js. It seems like discord.js only adds role to the guild where an event ran.

Comment: Why would you make an API call to your bot? Just do it directly to Discord in your website backend.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry if it's not what you want, I don't have a lot of informations

it will be anything like that:

```js
const guild = client.guilds.cache.get("GUILD ID")
if (!guild) return;

guild.members.cache.get("member id")
if (!member) return;

guild.roles.cache.get("role id")
if (!role) return;

member.roles.add(role)
```